# Replacing text in same column for all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large Excel file with several sheets. They all share the same structure.
I need to replace "old1" and "old2" with "new1" and "new2" in column E of all sheets.
This is what I came up with:

```
`Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("old1", "old2")
rplcList = Array("new1", "new2")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Range("E:E").Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht
Next x`
```

Unfortunately though this replaces the text in ALL cells, not just in E:E.
What should I do? Thanks in advance!
Enrico

Comment: Try replacing `SearchOrder:=xlByRows` with `SearchOrder:=xlByColumns`.

Comment: select column E and do Ctrl + F find and replace?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out how it is replacing anywhere but E:E but aside that, your array loop should be inside your worksheet loop; not the other way around.

Comment: No repro, works fine and replaces only in column E.

Comment: @QHarr - best to select all sheets first and Ctrl + H (opens it on the replace tab).   There's no need for VBA for this if you're only doing it the once.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
Sub GettingOlder()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    For Each s In Sheets
        With s
            .Range("E:E").Replace What:="old1", Replacement:="new1"
            .Range("E:E").Replace What:="old2", Replacement:="new2"
        End With
    Next s
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: This works and is much simpler than the original code and I love what you named the `Sub` :)

Comment: @Miqi180  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Oddly enough this doesn't work to me, it's replacing "old1" and "old2" anywhere with "new1111111111111111111111" and "new2222222222222222" :/

Comment: @EnricoGiai  then use Miqi180's solution.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent also Miqui180's solution is behaving like that. I literally have no idea why

Comment: @EnricoGiai Something strange is going on here...................... Do the cells in column **E** contain ***data*** or ***formulas*** ???

Comment: Adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` can be of help, maybe there are some event handlers modifying data.

Comment: @BrakNicku  Your idea is worth trying.