# Find Formulas in cell across multiple sheets and replace with a new formula but referencing a cell for portion of the formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro were I can search multiple spreadsheets in my workbook for a specific formula and replace it with a different formula but changing a variable within the formula as well.

So for instance, I want to find formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Actions_qry!$B$2:$B$40000,{"**NameofPerson**"},0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(Actions_qry!$D$2:$D$40000,{"FormType"},0)))
```

And replace it with Formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Actions_qry!$B$2:$B$40000,{"**NameofPerson**"},0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(Actions_qry!$D$2:$D$40000,{" FormType"},0)))
+ SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Actions_qry!$B$2:$B$40000,{"**NameofPerson**"},0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(Actions_qry!$D$2:$D$40000,{" FormType2"},0)))
```

In this formula though,  I need “NameofPerson” to reference cell B4 for the first iteration of the loop and then offset for a predetermined number of rows to reference the next person in the form.  The forms for each person are identical so they are spaced evenly throughout the form.  I have included a screen cap with what the form looks like to give a better reference.

[Screen Cap of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WgEb.png)

I have seen macros where people have made an array of stuff to find and then an array of stuff to replace but I was not able to adapt it to this.  It is a little more complex than my limited VBA skills.  I was trying to adapt this script by @Miqi180 to do it.  I am not sure I am even close to doing it though.  Like I said my VBA skills are limited, alike stumbling around in the dark.   Any advice or knowledge would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

[Replacing text in same column for all sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411913/replacing-text-in-same-column-for-all-sheets)

Sub replaceOldWithNew()

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("old1", "old2")
rplcList = Array("new1", "new2")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Range("E:E").Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "{" FormType"}" represent? So in your loop you start with B4 and then offset a certain amount each time at each iteration, and your current formula is repeated with a change to Form Type.

Comment: I have thirty+ different forms that the formulas grab.  Formtype and formtype1 are just to show that I want two different forms to be combined into one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the script working for what I needed.  I made the script go through column B and look for the row label.  If it found that row label, it then offset one cell to the right and pastes my new formula.  Inside the formula I made it reference a string which sets itself to the cell with the user's name by offsetting a set number of cells to get to the username.  Once it has pasted the first formula it then goes back to the row it found and offsets another cell to the right and pastes the next formula with the user's name inserted. Here is the code:

```
    Sub Replaceformulas()

    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    Dim sUserInput As String

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
            Select Case ws.Name
                Case "Tab1", _
                    "Tab13"
                    'Do nothing on these tabs


                Case Else 'If not one of the above tab names then do this
                    With ws.Activate
                        LR = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                        For i = 1 To LR
                            With ws.Range("B" & i)
                                If .Value = "My Value" Then 'Find the row i specify with My Value here
                                    ws.Select
                                    .Offset(0, 1).Select
                                    sUserInput = ActiveCell.Offset(-19, -1).Address
                                    ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(MYQuery!$B$2:$B$40000," & sUserInput & ",0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(MYQuery!$D$2:$D$40000,{""Criteria""},0)))+SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(MYQuery!!$B$2:$B$40000, " & sUserInput & ",0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(MYQuery!!$D$2:$D$40000,{""Criteria""},0)))"
                            .Offset(0, 2).Select
                            'This is my first formula I want to enter
                            ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIFS(MYQuery1!$D$2:$D$4525,MYQuery1!$B$2:$B$4525, " & sUserInput & ",Hours_qry!$C$2:$C$4525,""Criteria"")+SUMIFS(MyQuery2!$D$2:$D$4525,MYQuery1!$B$2:$B$4525, " & sUserInput & ",MYQuery1!$C$2:$C$4525,""*Criteria"")
                            'This is my second formula I want to enter
                            Debug.Print ws.Name
                        End If
                    End With
                Next i
            End With
        End Select
    Else
        MsgBox xlSheet.Name
    End If


    Next ws

    End Sub
```